# In the Django admin, "Add" and "Change" options are not appearing for a brand new simple model admin. Why?

Tags: python, django, admin, changelist

This is probably something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.  So I started a new app called proposals.  The following I entered into the app's `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Proposal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I then entered the following into `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from proposal.models import Proposal

class ProposalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Proposal, ProposalAdmin)
```

This seems incredibly straightforward, right out of the Django docs, but the "Add" and "Change" options for this admin are not appearing.  They do appear for everything else, but not this particular admin.  Any ideas on what might be causing this?

**UPDATE**

I'm continuing to check into this, and it's not a permission issue.  The permissions are all set to true for add / change / delete.  The template that generates the admin page requires a `model.add_url` for an "Add" link and `model.admin_url` for a "Change" link.  These attributes are missing for some reason.  Thus no links.  Why they are missing is the big question.

**UPDATE**

I finally discovered what was going on here.  An app which didn't need the add / change links was listed in the installed apps prior to this new one.  Whatever it's author did to cause these links not to appear ended up being inherited by all other apps that followed it in this list.  When I moved this new app above this one, the links appeared.  I didn't even know that it was possible for apps to affect each other like this, but that is something to look for in the future.

Comment: Usually when that happens to me it's because I've forgotten to add the new permissions to the appropriate user or group.

Comment: I considered that, but I'm a superuser and should be seeing everything.  And I do see everything else.  It's just this one thing.

Comment: Odd. Does the admin show up at all?

Comment: Yup.  Can link to `/admin/proposal/`, but that's it.  Initially I thought I had screwed up my environment somehow, but had some coworkers pull the branch down, and they're getting the same thing.  We are on Django 1.6.11 presently, BTW.

Comment: After reading your update, it still sounds like a permissions issue. The keys `model['add_url']` and`model['admin_url']` are set in the `AdminSite._build_app_dict`method of the user has the required permissions. I suggest stepping through that code to see why the keys are not added.

Comment: The permissions are fine.  I'm getting into the admin code, and the issue is that it's not finding a reverse match for the add and change urls.  That throws an exception and these items never end up in the dictionary.  The admin is registered and is appearing.  Unsure why these urls aren't being generated with the autodiscover.  Continuing to dig.

Comment: Since you've found the issue, you might want to post what you found as an answer. It's totally normal to answer your own question if you found the answer and no one else did: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question - though if you did this I at least would be interested in a link to the offending app (assuming it's third party and not proprietary) or the offending code snippet if you found the place where it modifies the admin in that manner.